# Select columns from both tables (one is derived) -- Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to select specific columns from both of my tables , one of which is a derived table, but for some reason i can only select *

This works:

```
SELECT *        
FROM        
    (

--Pivot the Custom Fields into a derived table--------------

        SELECT  [Id], [CustomField], [CustomField2], [CustomField3], [CustomField4], [CustomField5]
        FROM
                (
                    SELECT [Id], [FieldValue], [FieldName]    
                    FROM 
                    EntityCustomFieldValues 
                    AS t1
                    INNER JOIN Contact t2 ON t1.ParentId = t2.Id
                 )AS SourceTable 

                    PIVOT
                    (
                    MAX([FieldValue]) FOR [FieldName] IN ([CustomField], [CustomField2], [CustomField3], [CustomField4], [CustomField5])
                    )AS PivotTable

-----------------------------------------------------------
     ) AS t

    INNER JOIN Contact ON t.Id = Contact.Id
```

The problem is that once I try to select specific columns I get a syntax error???

```
    SELECT  [t].[Id], [Contact].[FirstName], [t].[CustomField], [t].[CustomField2],         
FROM        
    (

--Pivot the Custom Fields---------------------------------

        SELECT  [Id], [CustomField], [CustomField2], [CustomField3], [CustomField4], [CustomField5]
        FROM
                (
                    SELECT [Id], [FieldValue], [FieldName]    
                    FROM 
                    EntityCustomFieldValues 
                    AS t1
                    INNER JOIN Contact t2 ON t1.ParentId = t2.Id
                 )AS SourceTable 

                    PIVOT
                    (
                    MAX([FieldValue]) FOR [FieldName] IN ([CustomField], [CustomField2], [CustomField3], [CustomField4], [CustomField5])
                    )AS PivotTable

----------------------------------------------------
     ) AS t

    INNER JOIN Contact ON t.Id = Contact.Id;
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

I've tried to wrap this in another Select, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: You have a comma before the first `FROM`.

Comment: when you use `AS SourceTable ` I don't think you need the keyword `AS` there, although I am not much familiar with sql-server, so I might be mistaken

Comment: That's way too much time to spend on a comma... ....I always mess up some mundane detail...

Comment: @hatik AS is optional in SQL Server, but it works (and is useful for clarity)

Comment: @JeffUK good point to know, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT [t].[Id]
    ,[Contact].[FirstName]
    ,[t].[CustomField]
    ,[t].[CustomField2]
FROM (
    --Pivot the Custom Fields---------------------------------
    SELECT [Id]
        ,[CustomField]
        ,[CustomField2]
        ,[CustomField3]
        ,[CustomField4]
        ,[CustomField5]
    FROM (
        SELECT [Id]
            ,[FieldValue]
            ,[FieldName]
        FROM EntityCustomFieldValues AS t1
        INNER JOIN Contact t2 ON t1.ParentId = t2.Id
        ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT(MAX([FieldValue]) FOR [FieldName] IN (
                [CustomField]
                ,[CustomField2]
                ,[CustomField3]
                ,[CustomField4]
                ,[CustomField5]
                )) AS PivotTable
    ----------------------------------------------------
    ) t
INNER JOIN Contact ON t.Id = Contact.Id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one please:

```
    SELECT  [t].[Id], [Contact].[FirstName], [t].[CustomField], [t].[CustomField2]
    FROM        
    (

--Pivot the Custom Fields---------------------------------

        SELECT  [Id], [CustomField], [CustomField2], [CustomField3], [CustomField4], [CustomField5]
        FROM
                (
                    SELECT [Id], [FieldValue], [FieldName]    
                    FROM 
                    EntityCustomFieldValues t1
                    INNER JOIN Contact t2 ON t1.ParentId = t2.Id
                 ) SourceTable 

                    PIVOT
                    (
                    MAX([FieldValue]) FOR [FieldName] IN ([CustomField], [CustomField2], [CustomField3], [CustomField4], [CustomField5])
                    ) PivotTable

----------------------------------------------------
     ) t

    INNER JOIN Contact ON t.Id = Contact.Id;
```